# Serialize a tree structure to JSON using filters with jackson

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I have a `RestController` that returns the following tree structure:

```
@Data
public class TreeNode {
    private String description;
    private boolean enabled;
    private Set<TreeNode> children;
}
```

Depending on an input parameter I want to hide the nodes of the tree where `enabled` is `false` and I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require rebuilding the whole tree.

I had some success with extending `JsonSerializer` and adding that rule there, but it's quite cumbersome to have multiple `ObjectMapper`s in the controller (one with the serializer, one without) and pick the one based on the parameter.
Is there any easier way to achieve this?

Comment: What about going down the tree and trim off disabled children? Is that what you call rebuilding the tree ?

Answer (score 0):

What bout something like that? You go from the root, look up all the children and remove them if disabled. And if enabled you recursively call the same trim method.

You are not rebuilding the tree, you are cutting off the unwanted leaves:

```
// Example for this tree:
//          l0
//     l1        l2
//  l11  l12   l21 l22


TreeNode l11 = new TreeNode("leaf 11", true, Collections.emptySet());
TreeNode l12 = new TreeNode("leaf 12", false, Collections.emptySet());
TreeNode l21 = new TreeNode("leaf 21", true, Collections.emptySet());
TreeNode l22 = new TreeNode("leaf 22", true, Collections.emptySet());
TreeNode l1 = new TreeNode("leaf 1", true, new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(l11, l12)));
TreeNode l2 = new TreeNode("leaf 2", false, new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(l21, l22)));
TreeNode l0 = new TreeNode("leaf 0", true, new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(l1, l2)));



@RequestMapping(value="/api/v1/tree", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public TreeNode getTree(@RequestParam("full") int full){
    System.out.println("getTree full: "+full);

    if(full != 1) {
        trim(l0);
    }

    return l0;
}

private void trim(TreeNode treeNode) {
    for(TreeNode tn : treeNode.getChildren()) {
        if(!tn.isEnabled()) {
            treeNode.getChildren().remove(tn);
        } else {
            trim(tn);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

You can probably achieve this using a PropertyFilter

Create a filter that only allows enable nodes:

```
class EnabledTreeNodeFilter extends SimpleBeanPropertyFilter {

    @Override
    public void serializeAsField(Object o, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider, PropertyWriter propertyWriter) throws Exception {
        if(((TreeNode) o).isEnabled()) {
            propertyWriter.serializeAsField(o, jsonGenerator, serializerProvider);
        }
    }
}
```

Set a filter name for your class

```
@JsonFilter("enabledTreeNodeFilter")
class TreeNode {
    private String description;
    private boolean enabled;
    private Set<TreeNode> children;

    // Getters
}
```

Add the filter to your mapper

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

// Add this bit in an if, if you want to filter or not
SimpleFilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider();
filters.addFilter("enabledTreeNodeFilter", new EnabledTreeNodeFilter());
mapper.setFilters(filters);

// Then you can use your mapper
String treeNodeAsString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(l0);
System.out.println(treeNodeAsString);
```

Outputs

```
{
    "description" : "leaf 0",
    "enabled" : true,
    "children" : [ {
        "description" : "leaf 1",
        "enabled" : true,
        "children" : [ {
            "description" : "leaf 11",
            "enabled" : true,
            "children" : [ ]
        }, { } ]
    }, { } ]
}
```

Almost working, I am not sure how to get rid of the empty objects in the children arrays.

Comment: with that I'm loosing the non-enabled nodes from the tree, which is a problem when a request comes in for all nodes

Comment: @Balazs Would you be able to copy/clone the TreeNode before trimming it?

Comment: it would be about the same effort as it is to rebuild it. besides it will be a fairly big tree in terms of memory usage so cloning is not really an option.

Comment: @Balazs I had a go with a PropertyFilter, it almost work, have a look

Comment: I had a similar solution as your 2nd suggestion, but similarly to yours it wasn't exactly what I needed as there were some "remainings" from the disabled nodes.

Comment: What I would need is some sort of value filter on the array of children, but I couldn't find such thing in Jackson (apart from this: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/313)

Comment: @Balazs Seems like it, I noticed the feature to ignore the empty values in Maps, but couldn't find it for Lists or Sets.